# Query with many (equals by name) keys

Tags: python, django, django-templates

For example I have list with primary keys [1,2,3,4]
I want to do smth like this:

```
Player.objects.order_by('-cup_points').exclude(pk=[1,2,3,4])
```

But argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'. Can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `__in` lookup:

```
Player.objects.order_by('-cup_points').exclude(pk__in=[1,2,3,4])
```

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in

Comment: I remember discovering this a few years ago and it *totally* made my problem go away.

Answer (score -1):

OP: " .. argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'. Can I do this?"

Yes, given

```
li = [1,2,3,4]
', '.join(str(i) for i in li)
```

yields:

```
'1, 2, 3, 4'
```

a string which addresses your need to convert your list into a string, that you could then possibly use in your method above.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Yes, but maybe I misunderstood? OP had a list and wanted to use the values in a method that wanted a string or a number and didn't know how to do this. I provided a way to convert that list into a string which OP could use in that function. There might be better ways if you know Django (?) but how does my answer not meet the requirements of the question? Did I misread something?

Comment: @ChrisPratt there's no need to be snarky about this either, we are all trying to help.

Comment: It doesn't meet the requirements because it doesn't work. The OP is looking to exclude any items with those pks. The error he got, "must be a string or a number, not 'list'" is a generic error indicating that this is a foreign key field and foreign key's are either CHAR or INTEGER types. It *doesn't* mean that a string is actually acceptable, because his pks are ints. If he followed your advice and used that string, he'd be no closer to a solution because it still wouldn't match anything.